# Answered: Custom component inherit `Input` component in ant.d

Tags: antd

I want to make a custom component which adds a float label to e.g. `Input`. This sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-float-label-wrx4d?file=/FloatLabel/index.js) describes the process I'll use as guideline. Now the example has `Input` outside the custom component. I want to put it in the component for some things like placeholder will be determined dynamically.

Can you somehow inherit the `input` in the custom component so you don't have to pass all the possible properties and make new tests for them? Example, I'ld like to then pass `placeholder` to the custom component without setting it as a property. Maybe use some sort of `extend`?

Comment: Okay, I could make a class component extending `Input` and use render etc to change the display. Would this be the way to go, instead of a function component I'm making now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spread operator to do that.

```
export const CustomInput = ({yourCustomProps1, yourCustomProps1, originalInputProps}) =>{
  return(
    <div>
      // your label might be here
      <input {...originalInputProps}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And use it in a component

```
export const Component = () =>{
  return(
    <CustomInput originalInputProps={{type: "text", placeHolder: "Test"}} yourCustomProps1="Any thing you desire"/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps me out.

Comment: I am glad it helped